# Find coordinates of the center of the mass - line integral

Tags: calculus, 3d, curves, line-integrals

Find the coordinates of the center of the mass of the curve
$$ x^2+y^2=1,  x+2y+3z=12 $$

I find calculating line integrals in 3D problematic and really don't know how to approach this one. I think that the curve we get is an elipse but how to find its parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterise the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ as

$$(x,y) = (\cos(t),\sin(t)) \qquad t \in [0,2\pi]$$

as usual. Plug this into the other equation:

$$x+2y+3z=12 \implies \cos(t)+2\sin(t)+3z=12 \implies z = 4 - \frac{\cos(t)+2\sin(t)}{3}$$

So the parameterisation is

$$(x,y,z) = \bigg(\cos(t),\sin(t),4 - \frac{\cos(t)+2\sin(t)}{3}\bigg) \qquad t \in [0,2\pi]$$

Comment: Thank you so much!